# Why is the VirtualBox configured memory different from available memory within the VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I can't figure out a reliable conversion between what is set in the VirtualBox machine settings and the exact value which will appear as `MemTotal` in `/proc/meminfo`.

Some tested values

```
Configured(M)  /proc/meminfo (K)
1024           1008560
2048           2040752
4096           4039168
6000           5958144
7000           6965768
8096           8069636
```

Trying to linear fit that gets me `997*x-17133`.

The offset is easily explained with the default vram, but the ~1% error on that fit is what confuses me.

Any info on where the non-linearity comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemTotal is
[defined](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)
as:

> Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code)

The result is that MemTotal can change as it doesn't show memory utilized by the
kernel binaries themselves in memory.
Modules can be loaded and unloaded as required and may dynamically allocate memory,
which can become fragmented and grow.

The "missing" memory is the kernel itself. This can be minimized by reducing
the kernel, but is frankly not worth the effort and can hurt performance.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to get the actual full hardware size measurement?

Comment: Ah using that reference text I was able to find some more useful reference. Thanks again
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/why-does-linux-show-both-more-and-less-memory-than-i-physically-have-installed